# (Terraform, GCP) Error creating service account: googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.create is required to perform this operation on

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

On **GCP**, I'm trying to create **a service account** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-173831"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  display_name = "My Service Account"
  account_id   = "my-service-account"
}
```

But I got this error below:

> Error creating service account: googleapi: Error 403: Permission
> iam.serviceAccounts.create is required to perform this operation on
> project projects/myproject-173831., forbidden

So now, I'm trying to add a role to solve this error above but there are too many roles to choose:

[image]

What role do I need to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose the role **"Create Service Accounts"** to create service accounts:

[image]

In addition, you can choose the role **"Delete Service Accounts"** to delete service accounts:

[image]

Otherwise, you cannot delete service accounts then you will get this error below:

> Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.delete is required to
> perform this operation on service account
> projects/myproject-173831/serviceAccounts/my-service-account@myproject-173831.iam.gserviceaccount.com.,
> forbidden

Finally, if you want to create and delete service accounts with **one role**, you can choose the more abstract role **"Service Account Admin"**:

[image]